# Failed to load driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, driver

I am trying to run my Spring Boot backend with two profiles, one using H2 in memory database and the second one using MySQL. H2 database works just fine, but when I switch to MySQL I get

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: driverclassname
    Value: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I have tried deleting .m2, reimporting, maven clean, compile, install and most of the things I could find on the internet, no success. The funny thing is that I have other project with MySQL database only, I had similar issue, but adding **mysql-connector-java** dependency solved it. I have no clue right now.

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@profilename@

#H2 in memory database
domain.datasource.type=H2
domain.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:store;MODE=MYSQL;
domain.datasource.driver-class=org.h2.Driver
domain.datasource.username=sa
domain.datasource.password=
domain.datasource.generate-dll=true
```

**application-local_mysql.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@profilename@

#MySQL local database
domain.datasource.type=MYSQL
domain.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3600/store;
domain.datasource.driver-class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
domain.datasource.username=store
domain.datasource.password=store
domain.datasource.generate-dll=false
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sk.personal</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my-project</name>
    <description>My personal project.</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local_h2</id>
            <properties>
                <profilename>local_h2</profilename>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local_mysql</id>
            <properties>
                <profilename>local_mysql</profilename>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**DatasourceConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Value("${domain.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${domain.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${domain.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${domain.datasource.type}")
    private String type;

    @Value("${domain.datasource.driver-class}")
    private String driverClass;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        if (type.equals("MYSQL")) {
            return DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .username(username)
                    .password(password)
                    .url(url)
                    .driverClassName(driverClass)
                    .build();
        } else {
            EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
            return builder
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is so embarrassing. I appended the driver line of application.properties with a semicolon ...
Obviously, it did't recognize that driver.

Comment: Embarrassing for me too :)

Answer (score 84):

In my case the next dependency was missing:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In case of using IntelliJ and if you inherit from a `<parent>`, you can view your effective `pom.xml` by right clicking anywhere inside your `pom.xml`, then:
[image]

and search for the `mysql-connector-java` artifact as mentioned.

Comment: So in my case. The dependency was just missing

Comment: Gradle equivalent: runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

Comment: amigos :) this works of course

Answer (score 15):

I had a problem where I was using Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE and needed to connect to an old Mysql DB (5.1.73), which required me to downgrade to mysql-connector-java version 5.1.38

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
```

Since Spring boot was expecting a newer mysql-java-connector, which has been renamed to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, I also had to add the spring datasource driver-class-name setting in my spring boot db config.

So my spring boot config ended up like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
   url: 'localhost'
   password: password
   username: user
   driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 11):

just add mysql and jdbc dependencies like below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: After searching for a while, i got it working using "spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc". Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify version of MYSQL JDBC driver, so you're likely getting version **8.x**, where the driver is named differently than in previous versions:

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: I've had connector of version 5.1.47 and it didn't work so I've specified dependency version to 8.0.12, but still, Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver; in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Comment: The version 8.0 of the driver still contains the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

In my case error throws:

```
Property: driverclassname
Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
```

Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

So I have just added mysql dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Try upgrading your driver. Coz Mysql community has updated class name from **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.** [Check More Details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html)

Answer (score 2):

Change the database driver dependency scope to 'runtime'

For example:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.{yourDatabaseGroupid}</groupId>
        <artifactId>{yourDatabaseArtifactId}</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to your **application.properties** file .

My **application.properties : **

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.username=root
```

Answer (score 2):

this issue for me was also caused by the version of mysql.
all i had to do is add the version of mysql in pom.xml dependencies
(in my case the verion is 8.0.25)

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId> 
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.25</version> 
  </dependency>
```

make sure to reload the maven dependecies before your run

Answer (score 1):

I cant believe it!
In intellij: **Build->rebuild project** solved the issue for me!

[image]

For more information:

**pom.xml**:
[image]

**application.properties:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot 3.xx has updated its dependency

try this

```kotlin
runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
```

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. For me, it was because of having h2 database dependency!
I don't know how these two can affect each other, but all I did was removing this dependency and now it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Had to specify the jar path inside project->Properties->JPA-> connection Profile -> JAR List

[image: configuration screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I my case all configurations were correct but I still get this error.

In Intellij, go in the project structure (**ctrl + alt + maj + S**) in windows.
Look if u get some problems.

If yes, go on **maven** in the sidebar: clic on **"Generate sources and Update Folders for All projetct"**

That resolve my error !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the root cause was [ spring.**profile**.active ]
and the fix is [ spring.**profiles**.active ] where it is **profiles** plural
and it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

go to https://start.spring.io
In that site:
Dependencies > Search for Mysql drver > select it > Click explore button > copy the latest version of mysql connector > add it into your application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

/*I solved it just by placing these two lines.*/

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, here's another updated alternative (to `@Janac Meena`'s comment) for Gradle

```
implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.1.0'
```

Check for more versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j). My mistake was spelling the above as `mysql-connector-java:8.1.0` instead of `mysql-connector-j:8.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that:

1. I failed to add the MySQL connector-j dependency:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. I didn't correctly specify my database URL and configuration in my `application.properties` file:
3. While not necessary you can also add the driver-class-name in the `application.properties` file

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database-name
   spring.datasource.username=database-User-name
   spring.datasource.password=your-database-password
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   ```