# Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

how fix this problem ? /I use Gradle/
Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

```
Property: driverclassname
Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Comment: Is here answer for your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804228/failed-to-load-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Show your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I have seen it before. It don't work at my case.

Answer (score 6):

One day I woke up, ran my IntelliJ, started the app and had the same problem.
For a solution please check:

1. Dependency 'mysql:mysql-connector-java' is exists.
2. Class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' is exists through global search(ctrl+shift+n) -> classes.
3. In IntelliJ: "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart".